# Having separate columns as `type` with UNION, SQL query?

Tags: sql

I have two tables `sales` and `receivable`, and following is the query, which i am running and the output is a column `Type` with CREDIT & DEBIT but what i want is to have two separate columns, one for `CREDIT` and one for `DEBIT`. How can i have this output?

```
SELECT Date,SaleInvoice,VendorCode,sum(sales.Total),'CREDIT' as Type from sales 
UNION
SELECT Date,SaleInvoice,VendorCode,sum(receivable.Amount),'DEBIT' as Type from receivable 
ORDER BY SaleInvoice
```

Output of the above query;

```
Date        SaleInvoice  VendorCode  sum(sales.Total)   Type
2019-11-23     3           7100002       18613          CREDIT
2019-11-23     3           7100002       7200           DEBIT
```

and what is i want is to have separate column for CREDIT and DEBIT.

```
Date        SaleInvoice  VendorCode  sum(sales.Total)   Type1     Type2  
2019-11-23     3           7100002       18613          CREDIT
2019-11-23     3           7100002       7200                     DEBIT
```

Comment: Can you explain why this would be useful?  I cannot imagine why anyone would want two separate columns for "type" with  only one value in the column.

Comment: Actually i want to have credit and debit (values) in separate column rather than credit and debit (text) as separate columns, for reporting and reconciliation.

Comment: . . You don't have the values in separate columns in the question.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question if that is what you want.  In the meantime, you can accept the correct answer to this question.

Comment: Go the clue from scaisEdge and modified the query and i am getting what i want. thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use null column  where needed

```
SELECT Date,SaleInvoice,VendorCode,sum(sales.Total), 'CREDIT' as Type1, null Type2 
from sales 
UNION
SELECT Date,SaleInvoice,VendorCode,sum(receivable.Amount), null, 'DEBIT'  
from receivable 
ORDER BY SaleInvoice
```

Comment: Thanks scaisEdge, it gives the desired output. Though i have to work further on UNION. Marked as correct.